# scikit-learn's k-means: what does the predict method really do?

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

When I use scikit-learn's implementation of k-means I usually just call the `fit()` method and that is enough to get the cluster centers and the labels. The `predict()` method is used to calculate the labels and even a `fit_predict()` method is available for convenience, but if I can get the labels only using `fit()`, what is the purpose of the `predict()` method?

Comment: Won't the `predict` method be used on unseen data?

Comment: Makes sense. Since it was k-means I wasn't really thinking that way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand still. I have n observations and fit them using kmeans. I have n+1 observation so I could simply add that to my data set and fit all n+1 using fit(). Alternatively, we could use fit() and just use predict() on that n+1th observation. So do I understand correctly that in predict() we don't recalculate the centroids of our clusters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`predict`, as @EdChum suggested, can be used on unseen data. This (and more so, the `transform` method) is useful when k-means is used for feature extraction in semisupervised learning: you cluster a large set of samples, then use nearest centroid/distance to centroids as features for a subsequent supervised learning problem. When using the result for prediction, you get samples that were not seen by k-means.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the most recommended way to create a training set after applying k-means? I used dictVectorizer + tfIDFTransformer to obtain X and then executed km.fit(X), I want to use predict for a new document but I need to create a sparse matrix for it, what is the most efficient way to achieve that?