# What is the use of predict() method in kmeans implementation of scikit learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

Can someone explain what is the use of `predict()` method in kmeans implementation of scikit learn? The [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict) states its use as:

> Predict the closest cluster each sample in X belongs to.

But I can get the cluster number/label for each sample of input set X by training the model on `fit_transform()` method also. So what is the use of `predict()` method? Is it supposed to point out closest cluster for the unseen data? If yes, then how do you handle a new data point if you perform dimensionality reduction measure such as SVD?

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012342/scikit-learns-k-means-what-does-the-predict-method-really-do) but I still don't think it really helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what is the use of predict() method? Is it supposed to point out closest cluster for the unseen data?

Yes, exactly.

> then how do you handle a new data point if you perform dimensionality reduction measure such as SVD?

You apply the same dimensionality reduction method to the unseen data before passing it to `.predict()`. Here is a typical workflow:

```
# prerequisites:
#    x_train: training data
#    x_test: "unseen" testing data
#    km: initialized `KMeans()` instance
#    dr: initialized dimensionality reduction instance (such as `TruncatedSVD()`)    

# fitting
x_dr = dr.fit_transform(x_train)
y = km.fit_predict(x_dr)  

# ...

# working with unseen data (models have been fitted before)
x_dr = dr.transform(x_test)
y = km.predict(x_dr)

# ...
```

Actually, methods such as `fit_transform` and `fit_predict` are there for convenience. `y = km.fit_predict(x)` is equivalent to `y = km.fit(x).predict(x)`.

I think it's easier to see what's going on if we write the fitting part as follows:

```
# fitting
dr.fit(x_train)
x_dr = dr.transform(x_train)

km.fit(x_dr)
y = km.predict(x_dr)
```

Except for the call to `.fit()` the models used equally during fitting and with unseen data.

Summary:

- The purpose of `.fit()` is to train the model with data.
- The purpose of `.predict()` or `.transform()` is to apply a trained model to data.
- If you want to fit the model and apply it to the same data during training, there are `.fit_predict()` or `.fit_transform()` for convenience.
- When chaining multiple models (such as dimensionality reduction and clustering) apply them in the same order during fitting and testing.

Comment: Suppose that I've got some text data and I perform SVD on the its TDM and fit a kmeans model. I want to use this model on new text data. I can get TDM for new data with same vocabulary but I guess it'd be a problem if I apply SVD. The new features, although same in size, might not necessarily correspond to the previous decomposition. If I understand correctly, predict() method determines cluster by measuring euclidean distance with cluster centroid, then it won't make sense to measure distance if the features are not semantically corresponding, i.e. model's features and new data's features.

Comment: If you use the SVD's `transform` method it does not train the model again on the unseen data. It applies the same transformation as during training. However, I have never worked with text data before and do not know if whatever you put into the SVD can be consistent between data sets.